# Strategies for adapting classification algorithm to regression problems

Tags: r, regression, classification

I am the author of the [OneR package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=OneR) and more and more people approach me asking how to use this classification algorithm for regression problems.

At the moment two approaches exist:

- either the target variable is discretized (binned) and intervals get predicted or
- there is only a limited number of values and the target becomes a categorical variable (a factor in R lingo)

**My question**
Which general strategies can be used to adapt a classification algorithm to regression problems. A simple possibility I see is compressing the abovementioned intervals into their means.

**NB:** I am using OneR in this question as a concrete example, the answer could be more general. Also references are highly welcome.

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/615428/247274)

Comment: @Dave: this is the other way round?

Comment: I don’t think so. This is about binning a continuum and classifying into those buckets, right?